# Counter example of Nearest Point Property on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X=(C[-1,1], \| \cdot \|_\infty)$. Let $Y=\{f \in C[-1,1] : \int_{-1}^0 f = \int_0^1 f \}$ be a subspace.

Show that $Y$ doesn't have the nearest point property

Nearest point property: For every $x\in X$ there exists $y_0\in Y$ such that  $\| x-y_0 \| \leq \| x- y\|$ for every $y \in Y$.

Attempt:

I know that $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is a closed subspace.

Also, by definition of $Y$, every $y \in Y$ is symmetrical at $0$.

I also tried to proceed by contradiction.
Let $x\in X$. Suppose there exists some $y_0\in Y$ such that  $\| x-y_0 \| \leq \| x- y\|$ for every $y \in Y$.

But from here, I couldn't get anywhere. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What quantifiers do you have on $x$? Do you mean *some* $x$ exists? If $x$ is generic, it is false--take an $x\in Y,$ then the minimal distance of 0 is clearly attained.

Comment: I just edited the question. Hopefully, it's more clear now.

Comment: Hint: consider the linear functional
  $$
  \varphi (f)=\int_0^1 f(x)\,  dx - \int_{-1}^0 f(x)\,  dx,
  $$
  whose kernel is $Y$.  Next show that $Y$ has the nearest point property iff $\varphi $ attains its norm, and finally show
that the latter property does not hold.

Comment: When you say $Y$ attains its norm, does it mean that there exists some $y\in Y$ such that $\phi(y)= \| \phi\|$? Thanks!